# Derby SQL "wildcards"?

Tags: sql, wildcard

In re of my prepared (compound) statement, the date span search between the two dates works just fine. In the second part of this same query, I look for a match-up of a single "Ext" number ie: "103" from the jComboBox3 (a motel guest's room telephone ext number) .... this works fine as well. At times I wish to search for any undefined "Ext" number with-in this same query. I tried "*" and "%" (as a selection in jComboBox3) for this .... but not working. (column "Ext" is "varchar")

```
java.sql.Date dateStart = new java.sql.Date(jDateChooser2.getDate().getTime());// Check-In Date
            java.sql.Date dateEnd = new java.sql.Date(jDateChooser3.getDate().getTime());// Check-Out Date
            String i = (String)jComboBox3.getSelectedItem(); // Guest Room Extention Numbers  ie: 101,114,220,234 etc

            System.out.println(i);


            PreparedStatement st = null;
            try {
                st = con.prepareStatement("SELECT Date,Ext,Length,Trunk FROM TEST5 WHERE DateDate >= ? AND DateDate <= ? AND Ext=?");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainDisplay.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            st.setDate(1, dateStart);//set start date
            st.setDate(2, dateEnd);//set end date
            st.setString(3, i);
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
            jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

Comment: This potentially gets into the issues with SQL Injection hacks... but where your SELECT statement is concerned, just make Ext=Ext. Make sure you're not using the string "Ext", but Ext as a literal so it just checks its value against itself.

Comment: Didn't like that  :  (   java.sql.SQLException: The column position '3' is out of range.  The number of columns for this ResultSet is '2'.

Comment: Got it!   ("SELECT Date,Ext,Length,Trunk FROM TEST5 WHERE DateDate >= ? AND DateDate <= ? AND Ext LIKE ?");    :  )    With "%" chosen in jComboBox.

Comment: I removed "AND Ext = ?" ..... replaced with "AND Ext LIKE ?"